# Make textfield to only accept Even Numbers

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make an html text input field to only accept even numbers?

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZNu/96/ using angular js

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with some simple JavaScript. In the example below I just empty the textfield if the input is not an even number, you may want to do something more sophisticated.

Give your input field an onkeyup event like this

```
<input type="text" name="myinput" id="myinput" onkeyup="checkmyinput()">
```

And then write your javaScript function...

```
function checkmyinput () {
    // Get inputfield
    var inputfield = document.getElementById("myinput");

    // Get value from inputfield
    var inputval = inputfield.value;

    // Remove non numeric input
    var numeric = inputval.replace(/[^0-9]+/,"");

    // Check if input is numeric and even, if not empty field
    if (numeric.length != inputval.length || numeric%2 != 0) {
        inputfield.value = '';
    }
}
```

Try it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dgLrw80L/